# Express.js or angular routes for serving pug templates in a MEAN application?

Tags: angularjs, express, routes, pug, mean-stack

I'm a bit new to Mean Stack development and cant figure out how to approach the issue of serving my pug templates. Option One is having it confgured through angular and compile html with gulp. The other option is having it rendered through Express.  In last case I ran into an issue that express does not register angular ui route change hence the template is not being rendered. It only runs if I manully run the url.

Just in case here are my files so far

express routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mid = require('../middleware');

// GET /

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // return res.render('index', { title: 'Home' });
});

// GET /about
router.get('/tutorials', function(req, res, next) {
    // return res.render('tutorials', { title: 'Tutorials' });;
});

// GET /contact
router.get('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
    // return res.render('contact', { title: 'Contact' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Angular App.js

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$locationProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
    function($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });

  $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "views/index"
    })
    .state('tutorials',{
        url: "/tutorials",
      templateUrl: "views/tutorials"
    })
    .state('contact',{
      url: "/contact",
      templateUrl: "views/contact"
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

}]);
```

Express App.js (Configuration File)

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const app = express();


const stFolder = '/src';

// parse incoming requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// serve static files from /public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + `${stFolder}/public`));

// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + `${stFolder}/views`);

app.get('/partials/:filename', routes.partials);
app.use(routes.index);

// include routes
var routes = require(`.${stFolder}/routes/index`);

app.use('/', routes);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('File Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
// define as the last app.use callback
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

// listen on port 3000
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`App is running on localhost:${port}`);
});
```